# Arabic TTS (Text To Speech) Library for Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, arabic

In there an Arabic TTS for Android? Best if for free.

Answer (score 3):

other choices are  [Nuance](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/by-solution/customer-service-solutions/solutions-services/inbound-solutions/loquendo-small-business-bundle/tts-demo/arabic/index.htm), and [Voxygen](https://www.voxygen.fr/fr/content/expressive-speech-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - according to [this link](http://eyes-free.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/tts_apps.html).
Do a ctrl+f search for "arabic", you will see it.
It is called "Star Translate" and it says it is free :).
I'm not so sure if it is exactly a TTS or just a translator, but the website is titled "Speech Enabled Applications", so it's probably worth a try.

---

Also, according to [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/tts-for-android/browse_thread/thread/340e898f094c6ab3?pli=1), SVOX offers an Arabic TTS as well.

---

Let me know if any of these work :).

Comment: Thanks Mike, the first is actually a translator not a TTS, SVOX offers arabic, but not for free. I am still trying to figure out if you need to install svox on every device or just in you code. :)