# Android.Speech.TextToSpeech Arabic Language

Tags: android, locale, text-to-speech

I want to add Arabic Language support to my Android app. 
Anyone knows how to do that?

I think it's applicable since there is a Locale for Arabic "ar_EG"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On what level do you want the Arabic support?
If you are localizing UI there are a lot of efforts in managing the layouts, The Fonts, The String Resources And Also the Direction Of The Views (Right To Left)

IF you are focusing Only On Text To Speach, Please Give More Details And Maybe Reading The Answers In This Question Will [Help] ([Arabic TTS ( Text To Speach ) Library for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851384/arabic-tts-text-to-speach-library-for-android))

Answer (score 0):

Android is indeed supported the Arabic language since version  2.3;
So, you have to choose version 2.3 as the minimum target, lower version won't supported Arabic.

Also you can read this: [What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android)